# GAS - GET not working but POST does

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

My script executes fine and is able to return data from my spreadsheet when I run the script from the editor but it fails when I try to use cURL or Postman.

I **am** able to issue a POST to call `doPost(e)` and add an extra row to my spreadsheet from the given parameters. I would like to be able to issue a GET request to call my `doGet(e)` method which returns the rows of my spreadsheet as JSON (I verified that doGet works in the editor).

However, when I try to issue the GET using cURL or Postman I get `TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.`

I'm confused because I don't call the method `getRange()` at *all* in my script so I don't know where this error is coming from. I hardcoded the Spreadsheet key and worksheet name into the script for testing and I still get the same error.

I have deployed the web app so that it executes with my Google account and I allow `Anyone, even anonymous` to access the script. I have run a setup function to authorize my account with the script.

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AvXqpv9dPoVfdHRzRUkxMS1qVkpwaEJDSk44RXpZUVE&output=html) to my spreadsheet.

Here's my code:

```
function doGet(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AvXqpv9dPoVfdHRzRUkxMS1qVkpwaEJDSk44RXpZUVE");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clouds");

var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

var json = JSON.stringify(values);
Logger.log(json);

return json;
};

function doPost(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AvXqpv9dPoVfdHRzRUkxMS1qVkpwaEJDSk44RXpZUVE");
//var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter["sheetID"]);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clouds");

//Logger.log("sheetId: " + e.parameter["sheetID"]);
Logger.log("request: " + e);

//check if sheet exists, if not add sheet
if (sheet == null) {
  Logger.log("Creating new sheet...");
    //inserts sheet with specified ID, updates sheet var, appends a header row and then locks it
    ss.insertSheet(e.parameter["sheetID"]); 
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter["sheetID"]);
    sheet.appendRow(["ID","Coverage","Date", "Time", "Comments", "kWhr", "mL Water"]);
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1); 
}
//Append the 3 inputs to the sheet
//If statement takes care of whether the user is using the GET or POST functions, GET will have different parameter id's

if (e == null || e.parameter["id"] == undefined){
Logger.log("getting data");
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Successful GET");
//doPost(e);
}
else {
Logger.log("Appending row...");
sheet.appendRow([
  e.parameter["id"],
  e.parameter["coverage"],
  e.parameter["date"],
  e.parameter["time"],
  e.parameter["comments"],
  e.parameter["kwhr"],
  e.parameter["ml"]
]); 
}

//Returns a string to be displayed (If nothing is return you get a Google page saying the script worked and nothing was returned)
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Successfully Submitted. You may close the application"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I have to republish the code as a different version. Now everything works.